# Customizing Back Stack in Android Activities

Tags: android

Consider there is one activity, named Activity S.
Then there will be many activities, say 10 activities, named A, B, C, ..., J.

How can I achieve this:
From those A--J activities, when the back button is pressed, always go back to activity S.
Regardless of the ordering or how the activities are created.

For example:
Starting from S, go to B, then D, then G.
In activity G, press back button, and will go back to S.

== EDIT ==
Should I use `Activity.finish()` method when leaving all A--J activities ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish this in different ways depending on the exact result you desire. You could add the following line to your `<activity>` tags in your `manifest.xml` for those `Activities`

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

or use an `Intent` flag when overrdiing `onBackPressed()` in each

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, S.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`
    startActivity(i);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

this will clear the other `Activities` from the stack and return you to `S`.

If you want to keep the `Activities` on the stack while returning to `S` then you can change the flag used

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, S.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);`
    startActivity(i);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

The last way will bring `S` to the front and keep the other `Activities` on the stack which I don't think is what you want but just another option. You will probably want one of the first two ways.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer.. I want to ask a thing, does this situation is achievable by using `finish()` method when leaving every activity ?

Comment: It depends which one you do. The first one, yes. With the other two you don't need to unless you do other things in your `finish()` method because the super call will do that for you. But if you are asking if you want to do it not in `onBackPreseed()` then yes you would call `finish()` after using the `Intent`.

Comment: So the conclusion I learned is, (1) By default, `onBackPressed()` (or `super.onBackPressed()`) is simply calling `finish()` method. (2) Calling `finish()` when leaving every activity (starting another activity) is the same as giving `android:noHistory="true"` in manifest. Thank you and CMIIW. :D

Comment: 1) I wouldn't say that's all it does but finishing the `Activity` is part of the process unless you override it. 2) Yes. You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

You have to do like this to achieve, Set a flag that will Clear every activity from stack and pass intent to S.class, like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

    Intent intent=new Intent(this,S.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer.. I want to ask a thing, does this situation is achievable by using `finish()` method when leaving every activity ?